# Cluster assignment after estimate in a large dataset (Mclust)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, sampling, large-data

I've been doing a clustering analysis with a relative large dataset (~50.000 observations and 16 variables).

```
library(mclust)
load(file="mdper.f.Rdata")#mdper.f = My stored data
```

As my computer was unable to do it, I did a few subsets of information (10 x 5.000, 16.000 in the example, but 15min computing) and I was using Mclust to determine the optimal number of groups.

```
ind<- sample(1:nrow(mdper.f),size=16000)#sampling especial with 16.000, 15min cumputing 
nfac <- mdper.f[ind,]#sampling
Fnac <- scale(nfac) #scale data
mod = Mclust(Fnac) #Determining the optimal number of clusters
summary(mod) #Summary

#Results:
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust VII (spherical, varying volume) model with 9 components:

log.likelihood     n df    BIC      ICL
   128118.2 16000 80 255462 254905.3

Clustering table:
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
1879 2505 3452 3117 2846  464  822  590  325
```

Resulting always 9 (10 out 10 of datasets of 5.000), so, I guess it's okay.. 
Now, I would like to assign to the rest of the data the estimated cluster divisions in order to the multidimensional parts of the cluster.

How can I do it?

I started to play with the Mclust object but I can't see how to handle it and apply to the rest of the data. 
The optimal solution would be my original data with an extra column with the cluster number (1 to 9) assigned, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer after few minutes working:

First of all, there is a concept mistake, dataset must be scaled before partitioning and then just using **predict()**

```
library(mclust)
load(file="mdper.f.Rdata")#mdper.f = My stored data

mdper.f.s <- scale(mdper.f)#Scaling data 
ind<- sample(1:nrow(mdper.f.s),size=16000)#sampling with 16.000 
nfac <- mdper.f.s[ind,]#sampling
mod16 = Mclust(nfac)#Determining the optimal number of clusters, 15min cumputing with 7 vars

prediction<-predict(mod16 ,mdper.f.s )#Predict with calculated model and scaled data
mdper.f <- cbind(mdper.f,prediction$classification)#Assignment to the original data
colnames(mdper.f.pred)[8]<-"Cluster" #Assing name to the new column
```